# springboot JooqAutoConfiguration load before custom configuration

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

when I configure jooq with springboot,and I use a custom datasource,other configuration defer to the springboot auto-configuration.and when the web-application startup and get a datasource not found exception.it means JooqAutoConfiguration load before my custom configuration,but I move the custom configuration to the SpringApplication all it is ok.I do not why and I want to put the datasource configuration in persistence module not in Application.class in a maven project,thanks for help,look the code:
[image: custom datasource configuration class]
[image: Aplication.class]
[image: exception]
[image: exception]
[image: move datasource configuration to Application.class,all is going ok]

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshot use the correct tags for them so that the code is actual readable the same goes for stacktraces/errormessages.

Comment: ok,willco,and could you answser my question?